# Final vertex position in skeletal animation

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, 3d, transform

There is something I don't understand in skeletal animation.

I don't understand how to calculate the final position P of a vertex at the instant T using the matrix of all the joints affecting him.

What I'm doing at the moment is :

1. Calculating all the transform matrix of every joints in my skeleton for the instant T ; for now I'm doing my tests with an instant T which is a frame, so there is no interpolation needed (so I guess there is no mistake here)
2. Use the previously calculated transform matrix on the initial coords of a vertex V, like this :

   ```
   P=(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
   for every joints J affecting vertex V
       transformMatrix = J.matrix * weight
       P = P + transformMatrix * V.coord
   V.coord = P
   ```

Here I assume that the J.matrix of every joints are the right ones for the instant T. Am I doing something wrong in this calculation? I noticed I'm never using any inverse bind matrix, to be honest I don't really understand the aim of this matrix neither.

EDIT : Well, let's take an example to make things easier, tell me if you see any mistake.

I'm calculating the final position for a vertex V(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f).
Let's consider 2 bones are affecting V, B1 and B2, where :

B1 : Joint matrix J1 - Inverse bind matrix IBM1

```
[1][0][0][0]     [1][0][0][0]
[0][0][1][0]     [0][0][-1][0]
[0][-1][0][0]    [0][1][0][0]
[0][0][0][1]     [0][0][0][1]
```

B2 : Joint matrix J2 - Inverse bind matrix IBM2

```
[0][0][1][0]     [1][1][0][0]
[1][0][1][0]     [1][0][0][0]
[1][0][0][0]     [0][0][1][0]
[0][1][0][1]     [0][0][0][1]
```

The bind shape matrix BSM is

```
[0.5][0][0][0]
[0][0.5][0][0]
[0][0][1.5][0]
[0][0][0][1]
```

The weights are 0.6 and 0.4 for respectively B1 and B2, B2 is the child of B1.

What I'm doing is :

1. Calculating V * BSM, which is the same for every bones so I save it in R, which makes

   ```
   R = [-0.5][-0.5][-1.5][1]
   ```
2. Calculating R * IBM1 and R*IBM2, which gives me

   ```
   IM1=[-0.5][-1.5][0.5][1]   IM2=[-1][-0.5][-1.5][1]
   ```
3. Calculating IM1 * J1 and IM2 * J2, the result is

   ```
   X1 = [-0.5][0.5][1.5][1]    X2 = [-2][1][-1.5][1]
   ```
4. Ponderate the results with every bones weight, sum them and I'm considering this is the final position for V, the result is

   ```
   V = [-1.2][0.7][0.3][1]
   ```

Am I right by doing it this way? I saw some people using relative joint matrix, so for example here the joint matrix J2 would be the result of J1*J2. This is not what I'm doing here, is it a mistake?